# How to enable filter only for a subset of a field in the Django Admin list_filter option?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filter

In the Django Admin list_filter option , i want to enable filter only for a subset of a field. is that possible ? In the below code, i want to filter only a subset of the field 'status'. how ?

```
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'status', 'due_date', 'assigned_to', 'created_by', 'days_left')
    list_filter = ('status', 'due_date', 'assigned_to', 'created_by')
    search_fields = ['title']
    actions = [progressing, completed, canceled]
```

Thanks in advance,

Reenu

Comment: Would you like to filter over only the `status` field or over only specific values of the `status` field? Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to create new Filter inherited from `admin.SimpleListFilter` and then override the `queryset()` in it.

Good example is in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). Look for `DecadeBornListFilter` example.

Comment: Thank you primoz.. would give it a try.